# Design Pattern - Strategy Pattern in PHP

Tags: php

Take a look at the following code and let me know if its right, and if there is any room for improvements.

#### Strategy Class

```
<?php
/**
 * Draw Strategy class
 */
abstract class DrawStrategy
{
    abstract function draw(Shape $shape);
}
/**
 * This is ConsoleDraw and takes the shape object and draws accordingly, Drawign Algo is
 * implemented
 * here
 */
class ConsoleDraw extends DrawStrategy
{
    public function draw(Shape $shape)
    {
        echo "---------------";
    }
}

class WebDraw extends DrawStrategy
{
    public function draw(Shape $shape)
    {
        echo "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-";
    }
}
```

#### Shape Class ( That Composites Strategy Class )

```
<?php
/**
 * Design Pattern Impl. of Composite Pattern.
 *
 * Background:
 *
 * Shape is the Object, It can be specialised as Square or Rectangle and It can be drawn on
 * Web, or on Console / commandline
 *
 * The Drawing Algo is abstracted in Strategy Class and its used in the Shape Class
 *
 * Shape Class Uses DrawingStrategy and used accordingly, Uses ConsoleDraw, WebDraw as required
 *
 *
 */
include "strategy.php";

/**
 * Abstract Base Class Shape (Generalisation)
 *
 */
abstract class Shape
{
    public $length = 0;

    public function __construct( $_length )
    {
        $this->length = $_length;
    }

    /**
     * [draw this abstracts draw functionality]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    abstract function draw();

    /**
     * [area This is another function that calculates area]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    abstract function area();

}

/**
 *  SQuare Class Extends Shape and defines the implementation,
 *  It uses DrawStrategy as a component and so that it can draw either on the console or
 *  on the web.
 *
 */
class Square extends Shape
{
    public $length = 0;

    private $drawstrategy;

    public function __construct( $_length , DrawStrategy $_strategy )
    {
        $this->length = $_length;

        $this->drawstrategy = $_strategy;
    }

    public function area(){
        return $this->length * $this->length;
    }
    /**
     * draw - Takes up the Draw Strategy and draw on the current object
     * wether it is on console or web
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function draw()
    {
        $this->drawstrategy->draw( $this );
    }

}

class Rectangle extends Shape
{
    private $drawstrategy;

    public function __construct( $_length, $_breadth, DrawStrategy $_strategy )
    {
        $this->length = $_length;
        $this->breadth = $_breadth;

        $this->drawstrategy = $_strategy;
    }

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->length * $this->breadth;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        $this->drawstrategy->draw( $this );
    }
}

$shape[] = new Square( 4 , new ConsoleDraw );
echo "Shape 0 " .$shape[0]->area();
$shape[0]->draw();

$shape[] = new Square( 10, new WebDraw );
echo "Shape 1";
$shape[1]->draw();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there might be room for improvement.

First of all, Strategy pattern relies on interfaces / common classes and you are combining `Shape` with concrete Strategy passing it to the constructor.

To be more specific, here you bound `Square` with `ConsoleDraw` and `WebDraw`:

```
$shape[] = new Square( 10, new ConsoleDraw );
$shape[] = new Square( 10, new WebDraw );
```

The question is, what if I passed any `DrawStrategy` to the Square object? Should it work? Everytime? This is my point. I think you should **hide** allowed strategies on list behind the concrete Shapes and pass **context**.

Based on context, pick the right strategy (let's say, we are in **Console Context** - pick the ConsoleDraw. If we were on DesktopAppliction context - throw Exception "Unsupported" or don't draw at all).